# Is there a way to expand the scoped types of variadic template parameters in a parameter pack in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I would like to enforce that all types in a parameter pack have a nested type alias declared in them (`T`), and expand all the `T`'s of the types into a `tuple`. Is something like this possible? When I try the naiive way below, it doesn't recognize `Types::T` as a type.

```
class A { using T = int; };
class B { using T = double; };


template<class ... Types>
class C {
  using tuple_of_types_t        = std::tuple<Types...>;       // of course this works
  using tuple_of_nested_types_t = std::tuple<((Types::T),...)>;  // how do I achieve this?
};
```

Comment: Use `typename`:   `std::tuple<typename Types::T...>;`. [when to use typename, template keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: note that your `T` in both `A` and `B` is private, which will mess with the type checking

Comment: `type` is a more regular naming than `T` for typedef.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to be informed that `Types::T` should be interpreted as a *type*.

```
using tuple_of_nested_types_t = std::tuple<typename Types::T...>;
//                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

[See it compile on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6qTne4W4f)